# How to sort list with equal values in 1st column by by value of 2nd column in Excel or GSheet?

Tags: excel, sorting, google-sheets

I have this table:

| Date | Priority |
| --- | --- |
| Do., 07.01.21 | C |
| Di., 05.01.21 | B |
| Di., 05.01.21 | C |
| Do., 07.01.21 | D |
| Di., 05.01.21 | D |
| Do., 07.01.21 | B |
| Di., 05.01.21 | E |
| Do., 07.01.21 | A |
| Di., 05.01.21 | A |

As you can see it has a **Date** column and a **Priority** column.

If I sort this table I get the following results:

[Sorted List](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NnFvl.png)

Unfortunately the list is not sorted by the **Priority** column if the **values** are the same.

If I would have a guess, the fields are sorted by the time they have been created if they have the same value. Is there a way to sort from a second column if the first column is already successfully sorted?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want make sorting in place use `Sort range` dialog.

Select range which you want sort, go to `Data` -> `Sort range`, add columns and order to sort.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

try simple formula like:

```
=SORT(A:B, 1, 1, 2, 1)
```

sort range A:B in a way that 1st column will be sorted ascending and then 2nd column will be sorted ascending

Comment: Thank you, this was also the correct answer.